# multiple status with one response using cURL and php

Tags: php, curl, shopify

I have a cURL that get a response from a URL response, it is formatted like this:

`{"status": "OK", "tracking_id": "363070a8-53b6-49da-a7e9-6a289a3501f2"}`

Sometimes cURL executes more than once and I receive 1 to 5 different responses when I only execute it one time.

The URL I execute looks something like this:

```
    $request =  "https://precise-line.com/2/delivery/request?";
                $request.=  "api_key=".$api_key."&";
                $request.=  "user_id=".$user_id."&";
                $request.=  "delivery_type=".$delivery_type."&";
                $request.=  "route=E.+Pallares+y+Portillo&";
                $request.=  "street_number=110&";
                $request.=  "neighborhood=San+Lucas&";
                $request.=  "locality=Distrito+Federal&";
                $request.=  "administrative_area_level_1=Distrito+Federal&";
                $request.=  "postal_code=04030&";
                $request.=  "country=Mexico&";
                $request.=  "latlng=".$latlng."&";
                $request.=  "destination-route=".$destination_route."&";
                $request.=  "destination-street_number=&";
                $request.=  "destination-neighborhood=&";
                $request.=  "destination-locality=".$destination_locality."&";
                $request.=  "destination-administrative_area_level=".$destination_administrative_area_level."&";
                $request.=  "destination-postal_code=".$destination_postal_code."&";
                $request.=  "destination-country=Mexico&";
                $request.=  "destination-latlng=".$d_latlng."&";
                $request.=  "customer_email=".$customer_email."&";
                $request.=  "customer_phone=".$customer_phone."&";
                $request.=  "notification_email=&";
                $request.=  "notes=".$notes."&";
                $request.=  "dispatch=True";

 error_log("Request");
            error_log(print_r($request, true));

            $ch_request=curl_init();
            $curl =  curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
            //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close ($curl);

            error_log("Response");
            error_log(print_r($response, TRUE));
```

How can I prevent cURL from executing more than once?

Comment: should not run more than once, unless you call it more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you have both $ch_request and $curl? I don't know if that makes a difference, but you should delete that line with $ch_request. Otherwise, as Dagon said, you shouldn't have multiple responses if you call it once.

Comment: Yes i have this mistake, i copy other code but do the same... So is not cURL that makes it the multiple responses maybe could be other thing?